# Relationship between hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks and hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split

Tags: hadoop, hive

There are two properties in hive related to skew join.

```
    <property>
    <name>hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
        Determine the number of map task used in the follow up map join job for a skew join.
        It should be used together with hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split to perform a fine grained control.
    </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split</name>
    <value>33554432</value>
    <description>
        Determine the number of map task at most used in the follow up map join job for a skew join by specifying
        the minimum split size. It should be used together with hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks to perform a fine grained control.
    </description>
</property>
```

But I still don't understand what is the relationship between these two as `hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks` defines the number of map tasks and `hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split` also finally defines the number of map tasks.

Comment: `min.split` defines a *size of bytes*, not a number of tasks

Comment: @cricket_007 Please read the description carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading over

> tasks at most used... by specifying the minimum split size.

Which means, it calculates the total size of the inputsplits, divides by the split size property, then determines how many map tasks should be created, with a limit of total tasks created defined by the other property, which is why it says "fine grained control"